# String with literal_eval

Tags: python-3.x, eval, literals

can someone help me here? what is going on? why the string without(key=name) the spaces work and the string with(key=caption) the spaces fail?

```py
import ast
a = {'caption': 'A silhouette of two wine glasses clinking together against a beautiful sunset background, symbolizing connections and romance for over 50 singles.', 'name': 'images/MJ/94122817f243925a.PNG', 'size': '(1024, 1024)'}
for k, v in a.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
    print(ast.literal_eval(v))
```

results:

```
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    A silhouette of two wine glasses clinking together against a beautiful sunset background, symbolizing connections and romance for over 50 singles.
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why use `ast.literal_eval()` here? You already have the value.

Comment: It comes from DB and sometimes it is not str and its Python object such as dict or list, but I want to understand the issue with/without spaces

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` evaluates a string as if it were Python code. The sentence `A silhouette of two ...` is not valid Python code.

Comment: `It comes from DB and sometimes it is not str and its Python object such as dict or list` So what's the ultimate goal? I assume you don't want it to be a dict or list, and want to convert it to something else.

Comment: I push objects to my DB. The objects can be dict/list/str. But the DB only accept its str representation. So at push, I convert it to str, at pull I want to restore the actual object. This is the reason I used ast, and it seems like str makes issues here